# UI not updating in viewController MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I'm learning MVVM in swift. I setup the viewModel right but the ui is not updating, what went wrong actually I made the services as a singleton service parameter? this my code setup

```
class UserViewModel {

    private var user: GTUser?
    let service: UserService

    var id: String {
        return user?.userId ?? ""
    }

    var userName: String {
        return user?.fullName ?? ""
    }

    var imageUrl: String {
        return user?.docAwsUrl ?? ""
    }

    init(service: UserService) {
        self.service = service
        populateUser()
    }

    private func populateUser() {
        service.getUserData { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let user):
                self.user = user
                print(self.user)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

let services = UserService()
var viewModel: UserViewModel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupNavigation()
        configure()

        viewModel = UserViewModel(service: services)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.profileImage.getUserImage(urlString: self.viewModel.imageUrl)
            self.profileLbl.text = self.viewModel.userName
        }
    }
```

I already try using dispatchQueue but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your `private func populateUser()` function is Async function  so when you try to access  `self.profileImage.getUserImage(urlString: self.viewModel.imageUrl)` from `viewDidLoad` it might not be available,

So to fix this you can have a completion handler closure into function and on success and failure call the completion handler so after you can perform the operation

like

your init func will take a closure

```
init(service: UserService,completion:(Bool) -> ()) {
    self.service = service
    populateUser(completion)
}
```

and

```
private func populateUser(_ completion:(Bool) -> ()) {
   service.getUserData { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            self.user = user
            print(self.user)
            completion(true)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
           completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

and Now

```
 viewModel = UserViewModel(service: services){[unowned self] (success) in
        //Check success if you want !!
        self.profileImage.getUserImage(urlString: self.viewModel.imageUrl)
        self.profileLbl.text = self.viewModel.userName
    }
```

Hope it is helpful